# Best way to deploy a WCF service on AWS when using MSMQ

Tags: wcf, iis, amazon-web-services

We have a set of WCF services that use to MSMQ. We use the static web.config file to indicate to the services where the MSMQ host is.

Moving to AWS, we now need to dynamically specify the MSMQ host address. We figure we can pick between 2 options:

1) Write a script to update the web.config files when spinning up the AWS instances.

2) Drop the config files and implement a helper function that will resolve the MSMQ host address at runtime.

Anyone has any insight on what approach would be better or be considered best practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using solution #1. 
This was a trivial script to write and now we can use environment variables anywhere in our web.config files (not just to set the MSMQ endpoints).
Keeping the MSMQ config in the web.config files also allows us to change queue technology if/when needed by using other bindings (ex: RabbitMQ) with no changes to the source code.